# Serialize a hierarchical structure of objects in java

Tags: java, object, serialization, tree, hierarchy

I have an abstract class `Screen` and child classes: `GameScreen`, `SpellScreen`, `StatsScreen`, etc.

The game works in this way: a `Renderer` class creates a root

```
    Screen screenRoot = new GameScreen()
```

which then is free to add screens to itself, which then may add screens to themselves and so it goes. Therefore a tree-like structure is formed, every Screen containing a list of its child-screens.

Now I am wondering if it's possible to perform serialization and deserialization on that - I'd like to recreate all the screens in the same hierarchy.

Is it enough to serialize only the screenRoot object, and then deserialize it (provided I want to preserve the whole screens tree), or do I need to traverse the tree myself somehow?

How would you go about serializing this?

P.S. the game is for Android and uses OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: I suggest separating UI, logic and data (MVC), so you can use POJOs as simple typed data objects for serialization (perhaps using Json or XML with JAXB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hierarchy of objects is no impediment to using Java Serialization, as the latter can cope with arbitrary object graphs - and yes, serializing an object using Java Serialization will serialize all objects it refers to (unless that reference is marked `transient`). Assuming that's what you want, serializing the hierarchy is as simple as:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename)))) {
   oos.write(rootScreen);
}
```

and reading as simple as:

```
try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)))) {
    return (GameScreen) ois.readObject();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here.

First, screens should be just that--screens. They shouldn't contain the "model" or object data that represents your game state; only the view/rendering of that state. So serializing and deserializing, doesn't really make sense. I would suggest looking at your architecture again to see if this is really what you want to do.

If you decide to do it, or if you have another game-state object root that you can serialize (I usually use the `Player` since it has all the essential data in it), you can easily do this with [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
// Save
RootObject o = ...; // The root of the hierarchy to serialize
Gson gson = new Gson();
String serialized - gson.toJson(o); // JSON object, eg. { "Player": { ... } }

// Load
RootObject deserialized = gson.fromJson(serialized, RootObject.class);
```

You can read more in their [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Second, on the issue of `JSON` and `Gson`: I prefer this over standard serialization, because it's robust in the face of changes. If your class definitions change, you can still deserialize objects (albeit you get null/empty fields) instead of a runtime exception; you don't need to worry about versioning your classes, either.

Edit: questions like this are better suited to the [Game Dev SE site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I accepted meriton's answer because it's precisely what I am going to do now.

Comment: Your input helps a lot though, I do see that the design I planned is far from solid (SOLID, too...). It's far from MVC as well, and there's a tight deadline (it's my BSc game :)).
Is there any particular resource you could recommend to me as far as learning good architecture goes? (focused on practice/examples rather than theory).
Gson/Json looks nice, I'll try that too to learn.

Comment: I updated my answer to mention why Gson is awesome over serialization. I suggest focusing on the minimal changes you need to get done, and using "stories" (small, user-facing pieces of functionality) + version control. That goes a long way.

Comment: So, I had to let go of serializing the Screens. That was too much trouble; the objects were too complex. Couldn't get it to work both technically and logically. I decided to store only some critical data... first tried with Gson, but I couldn't manage to store Class variable as Json. 
Serializable gives me the possibility to serialize a Class variable "for free", therefore I went that way. Too bad Gson can't do that by default.

Comment: @PawelP why would you ever want to serialize instances of `Class`? You can do other things, like store the name and reflectively load it at runtime. Serialization is not necessary.

Comment: You mean serialize the class name as a string, and use Class.forName(string) after deserialization, yes? I'll give it a try.
I went the Class way because Class<? extends Opponent> looked neat. I like Gson's independence of Serializable interface, though.